# Continue executing ant script if one task fails

Tags: ant

I have an Ant script which runs tests then deploys my application to a QA server. To deploy the application it first calls `sun-appserv undeploy`, for various reasons the application may or may not be deployed. If the application is not deployed then undeploy fails and the whole script halts.

Is there some way that I can tolerate a failure on one task, log it, and let the rest of the script run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AntContrib try catch:

```
<trycatch>
<try>
   <!-- do deployment getting return code -->
</try>
<catch>
   <!-- echo the return code with a message -->
</catch>
</trycatch>
```

The exec task has a failonerror attribute which you can set to false to keep going.

Comment: It appears that the ant-contrib try/catch pair has to be enclosed in a <trycatch> tag.

Comment: I agree and have modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar to this and found an alternative method that is useful if you want to run a lot of tasks that have no dependency on each other and you want to know if all 5 of them fail without having to fix the first one.

Enclose all the tasks in a parallel task with threadCount set to 1. It's definitely a mis-use of the parallel task but accomplishes my goal:

```
<parallel threadCount="1">
    <fail message="fail 1"/>
    <fail message="fail 2"/>
    <echo message="Success"/>
    <fail message="fail 3"/>
</parallel>
```

Running this in a target gives this for output:

```
test:
     [echo] Success

BUILD FAILED
C:\test\build.xml:5:
fail 1
fail 2
fail 3

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

See the `-keep-going` option documented [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)