# How to continue if any of the antcall fails?

Tags: android, ant, antcall

I am trying to run an ANT script. In which I am calling multiple targets.

```
              <target name="mySuite">
                <antcall target="TC1"> </antcall>
                <antcall target="TC2"> </antcall>
                <antcall target="TC3"> </antcall>
                <antcall target="TC4"> </antcall>
                <antcall target="TC5"> </antcall>
                <antcall target="TC6"> </antcall>
                .
                .
                .
              </target>
```

My ANT script fails if any of the antcall target fail. But I want my ANT script to continue even any of he antcall target fails. What changes do I need to do?

Comment: More general: how to continue if a task fails: [Continue executing ant script if one task fails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7917359/772981).

Comment: Is not this default behavior? It should discontinue if any of the target fails! That's how it works for myself in Ant 1.8.2