# Apache Ant call when target fails

Tags: ant

I'm trying to call an Apache Ant target when another target fails and I can't find the correct way to do it...

```
<target name="BookingProcess">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="php" failonerror="false">
        <arg line="bin/behat --format progress --config features/Desktop/BookingProcess.feature --rerun"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="BookingProcessRerun">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="php" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="bin/behat --format progress --config features/Desktop/BookingProcess.feature --rerun"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

I want to call BookingProcessRerun only when BookingProcess fails.

Comment: If you do it manually, then how do you identify that the result is success or failure? Based on that probably you can read that console output and parse it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continue executing ant script if one task fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917359/continue-executing-ant-script-if-one-task-fails)